# How do I write unit test for code that should fail to compile in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I wrote most of my unit test with the help of the `unittest` module, but I’m not sure how to use it for code that the compiler should reject at compile time.  For example, if I want to write the following code and make sure the compiler always errors during compilation (the type and template would be in a separate module), how do I write a test case for this?

```
import macros
type
  T[n:static[int]] = object
template foo3(n: int): expr =
  static:
    if n > 3: error "n > 3"
  type T3 = T[n]
  T3
var
  bar: foo3(4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something similar with the `compiles` magic, provided by the system module.

Here is an example from the compiler test suite: 
https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/devel/tests/metatype/tbindtypedesc.nim#L19

Notice how at the top of the file, we define `accept` and `reject` as simple static assertions using the `compiles` magic and we use them throughout the file to test valid and invalid overloaded calls.

Personally, I think failing at compile-time is better, but you can assign the result of `compiles` to a run-time value or use it in a `check` statement. The only advantage of this would be that failures will be reported in the standard way for the unittest library.

Comment: The compilation still aborts when hitting the first `error` call, even within `compiles`.  So there is no way to automate the test.

Comment: I also couldn’t find a way to save the result of `compiles` to a runtime value for writing with `unittest`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an example of how to combine `check` with `compiles`:

```nim
template notCompiles*(e: untyped): untyped =
  not compiles(e)

# usage in unit tests:
check:
  notCompiles: 
    does not compile
  notCompiles:
    let x = 1    # would fail
```

I'm using a template, because combining the `not` with the block directly is not possible, and I don't want to use parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/shaunc/cucumber_nim/blob/b1601a795dbf8ea0d0b5d96bf5b6a1cd90271327/tests/steps/dynmodule.nim

I have a wrapper that compiles and loads a nim source module. Of course, you won't want to run it, but the technique might work for you:

```
  sourceFN = "foo.nim"
  ... (write source) ...
  libFN = "foo.dll"
  let output = execProcess(
    "nim c --verbosity:0 --app:lib $1" % sourceFN,
    options = {poStdErrToStdOut, poUsePath, poEvalCommand})
  if not fileExists(libFN):
    echo "COULDN'T COMPILE"
```